# Find index.html files & Rename with folder name and move file a level up

Tags: shell, find, xargs

Little help in solving a workflow with shell script using the find command.

1. Finding all index.html files in every folder.

   We can use this with find command for that.

   ```
   find ./ -type f -name 'index.html'
   ```
2. Renaming the file index.html with the folder names.
3. After renaming the files, I wanted to move the files one level up.

I'm stuck at renaming and moving the files one level up.

As I have more than 100k files, Xargs will be handy for this.

Here is code I have so far

```
find ./ -type f -name 'index.html' | xargs -P 4
```

Any help in in renaming the index.html files and moving the files one level up?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of xargs you can use find -exec. Inside, you can run a small sh-Script:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'index.html' -exec sh -c '
    d="$(dirname "$1")";
    mv "$1" "$d/../$(basename "$d").html";
    rmdir "$d";
' find-sh {} \;
```

Received the help from Askubuntu forum for it :)

Reference : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236564/find-index-html-files-rename-with-folder-name-and-move-file-a-level-up